# Tyepscript: Property 'join' does not exist on type 'typeof Prisma'

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm using Prisma in a Typescript project.
When handling variables within queryRaw, the documentation states that Prisma.join should be used.

Reference documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/queries/raw-database-access/raw-queries#tagged-template-helpers

However, when I actually executed the code, Prisma did not include the join.

```
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
const results = prisma.$queryRaw`select A as test from B where xxx in (${Prisma.join([1,2,3])})`;
```

Are there any other steps required?